# Downgrade Subversion 1.8 working copy to 1.7

Tags: macos, svn

Has anybody already managed to downgrade from Subversion 1.8 to Subversion 1.7? The provided script at http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/change-svn-wc-format.py only handles Subversion up to 1.6.

Comment: Subversion 1.7.10 and 1.8.0 was installed via homebrew.

Comment: why do you want to downgrade a working copy?

Comment: Because I installed subversion 1.8 from homebrew, upgraded the repository, and then found out there is no working unicode path patch for 1.8 yet.

Comment: @bahrep Or because IntelliJ IDEA does not support 1.8 yet. It is save to assume that anybody who asked for a downgrade has a compatibility problem.

Comment: Yeup, I got burned by this too....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I read this correctly, there is no way to revert back. http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.8_releasenotes.html#compatibility (According to TortoiseSVN)

Answer (score 10):

- Commit any uncommitted work or save uncommitted work if you are unable to commit with 1.8 SVN.
- Delete or rename working directory.
- Uninstall your 1.8 SVN client.
- Install 1.7 SVN client.
- Checkout repo again. Working copy is now 1.7 format

Comment: That is not downgrading, but a new checkout (I actually went that way) - but thanks anyway. Because of a nasty UTF8-Bug, committing uncomitted work in a directory with German umlauts would be problematic.

Comment: @tholu if you don't mind, please share, whether that UTF8 bug only applies on mac osx or also on other systems?

Comment: The UTF8 bug is OS X only and is already 8 years old and still not fixed: http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2464

Comment: ~ "Install 1.7 SVN client." How does one do that?

Comment: Igor, are you using homebrew? Then you should look at: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions

Answer (score 10):

Since both Subversion 1.7 and 1.8 have a single `.svn` folder in the root directory (unlike `1.6` and lower) you can use the following simplified procedure:

1. Install subversion 1.7 for your OS. If you are on osx and use `homebrew`, you can do it by running the following commands in terminal:

   `brew tap homebrew/versions
    brew install subversion17`

   Now, assuming you are in the root of your working copy:
2. Rename the `.svn` folder in your working copy (just in case you'll need to restore later):

   `mv .svn .svn18`
3. Do a new checkout in a temporary folder using subversion 1.7:

   `svn co http://myrepo.com/ /tmp/v17`
4. Copy only the `.svn` folder created by subversion 1.7 to your working copy:

   `cp /tmp/v17/.svn .`

Comment: So how is this simplified? You need to checkout again also.

Comment: @tholu: If you had local changes or new untracked files you won't need  to worry about stashing them and adding them to the clean 1.7 repo.

Comment: Before coming here, I was thinking of copying my added/changed files to the new working copy, but copying the .svn folder from that to the old working copy is a bit simpler. Thanks! I think this is the best answer.

Comment: `svn --version` still says I'm on v1.8. =[

Answer (score 0):

I success to downgrade svn from 1.8 to 1.7 by following this post: [Install a Specific Version of a Tool on OS X With Homebrew](http://gotofritz.net/blog/geekery/install-specific-version-homebrew/)。

Uninstall the previous version:

```
$ brew uninstall svn
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/svn /usr/bin/svn1.8
```

Find out how old versions are called:

```
$ brew search subversion
subversion
homebrew/versions/subversion16  homebrew/versions/subversion17
```

Install old versions：

```
$ brew tap homebrew/versions
Cloning into '/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-versions'...
remote: Counting objects: 1022, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (566/566), done.
remote: Total 1022 (delta 585), reused 873 (delta 456)
Receiving objects: 100% (1022/1022), 250.05 KiB | 428 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (585/585), done.
Tapped 98 formula

$ brew install subversion17
==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=subversion/subversion-1.7.10.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/subversion17-1.7.10.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/subversion17/1.7.10 --with-apr=/usr/bin --with-ssl --with-zlib=/usr --with-sqlite=/usr/local/opt/sqlite --with-serf=/usr/local/opt/serf --disable-neon-version-check --disable-mod-activation --disable-nls --without-apache-libexecdir --without-berkel
==> make
==> make install
==> make tools
==> make install-tools
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/subversion17/1.7.10: 106 files, 7.7M, built in 3.1 minutes
```

After downgrade, you may encounter the sqlite version error, you can refer this post if it do happen: [Subclipse error "svn: SQLite compiled for 3.8.6, but running with 3.8.5"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904364/subclipse-error-svn-sqlite-compiled-for-3-8-6-but-running-with-3-8-5/30646810#30646810)