# Downgrade Subversion 1.9.4 to 1.7.22 in Mac os

Tags: macos, svn

Anybody can help me? Step by step please. Thanks a lot.
I'm try [Downgrade Subversion 1.8 working copy to 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217733/downgrade-subversion-1-8-working-copy-to-1-7) but not usefull. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can install svn version 1.7 via **MacPorts**.

Follow the instructions [here](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=1619).

**Basically you'll have these steps**:

- Use the App Store to install Xcode.
- Note — you may need to update Xcode after installing it.
- Open a terminal and sudo xcode-select --install to install the the developer command line tools.
- Install [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php) for your version of OSX.
- Note — you may need to source ~/.bash_profile after installation for the port command to be found.
- Reinstall ports following the [migration](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration) instructions.
- The default install of Macports install links into /opt/local/bin and /opt/local/sbin, so add that to your path (then source ~/.bash_profile again).
- Use 'which svn' and/or 'svn --version' in bash to determine which copy of subversion you are using.